# How to get access to a Jpanel in GUI from another class

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to know the simplest way to get access to a JPanel in a GUI that was created using the drag and drop in NetBeans from another class. I'm trying to get the size of the JPanel in this other class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access from a class where the gui object created then create a public method to get the value. Ex,

```
public class Gui extend JPanel {
    public Dimension getPanelSize(){
        // Get Value code here
    }
}

Gui gui = new Gui();
gui.getPanelSize();
```

Or Keep the value static which can be accessed from anywhere. Ex,

```
public class Gui extend JPanel {
    public static Dimension dimension = null;

    public Gui {
        dimension = // Initialise value here
    }
}

Gui.dimension
```

Note : Static context is same for all objects

Comment: Not from the same class but from another class

Comment: then use 2nd method.